# iTunes Podcast feed doesn't show episodes

Tags: rss, itunes, podcast

I've created a RSS 2.0 feed for my podcast, but when I test it in iTunes (Advanced -> Subscribe to podcast..) no episodes are showing.

I haven't yet added iTunes specific tags, since I though they were not required. Are they? Is there any way to debug why it's not working? It is a valid RSS 2.0 feed according to W3C's feed validator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<link>`s in your `<item>`s should be `<enclosure>`s instead.  See the [feed specs example feed](http://www.apple.com/itunes/podcasts/specs.html):

```
<enclosure url="http://example.com/podcasts/everything/AllAboutEverythingEpisode3.m4a" length="8727310" type="audio/x-m4a" />
```

Comment: Oh, missed the example. Thank you, that must be it